# C++ clamp function for a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void Clamp(std::vector<double>& input_image, double min_value, double max_value, int width, int height)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            input_image[i*width + j] = std::min(std::max(input_image[i*width + j], min_value), max_value);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create this functionality of clamping.

Is there a better way to do it using a `std::vector`?

I can also use C++11

Comment: How about [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a simple lambda? Since you iterate over all elements of the vector anyway, the `width` and `height` arguments are actually not needed.

Comment: If you can do it in C++17, try to use [`std::clamp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) on the values, instead of spelling it out with min and max. It's more readable. And if you can't, well use your own clamp template instead.

Comment: @StoryTeller hey thanks I can't use c++17 for now. thanks

Comment: @Gilad Then may I suggest you make a compatible `clamp` function so it's easy to switch to `std::clamp` later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), assuming that you apply your function to every element then there is no need for the height and width parameters. Splitting the min and max operations seems more SIMD friendly, thus I suggest:

```
void Clamp(std::vector<double>& input_image, double min_value, double max_value)
{
    std::transform(std::begin(input_image), std::end(input_image), std::begin(input_image), [max_value] (double d) { return std::min(d, max_value); }
    std::transform(std::begin(input_image), std::end(input_image), std::begin(input_image), [min_value] (double d) { return std::max(d, max_value); }
}
```

Otherwise a C++11 way could be to use a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
void Clamp(std::vector<double>& input_image, double min_value, double max_value) // removed hight and width
{
    for (double& d : input_image)
    {
        d = std::min(std::max(d, min_value), max_value);
    }
}
```

Or the more SIMD "friendly":

```
void Clamp(std::vector<double>& input_image, double min_value, double max_value) // removed height and width
{
    for (double& d : input_image)
    {
        d = std::max(d, min_value);
    }
    for (double& d : input_image)
    {
        d = std::min(d, max_value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

C++17 has `std::clamp`. Also there's no need for the `height` and `width` parameters in this case.

```
void clamp_vec(std::vector<double>& input_image, double min_value, double max_value) {
    std::transform(std::begin(input_image), std::end(input_image), std::begin(input_image),
                   [=] (auto i) { return std::clamp(i, min_value, max_value); });
}
```

Template version for generic types will work as long as operator `<` is defined:

```
template <typename T>
void clamp_vec(std::vector<T>& input_image, const T& min_value, const T& max_value) {
    std::transform(std::begin(input_image), std::end(input_image), std::begin(input_image),
                   [&] (const T& v) { return std::clamp(v, min_value, max_value); });
}
```

If `std::clamp` is not available, you can implement your own until C++17 comes around, *e.g.*:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr const T& clamp(const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi) {
    return clamp(v, lo, hi, std::less<>());
}

template <typename T, typename Compare>
constexpr const T& clamp(const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi, Compare comp) {
    return comp(v, lo) ? lo : comp(hi, v) ? hi : v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd just do it in one pass and let the optimiser do its work.

```
void Clamp(std::vector<double>& input_image, double min_value, double max_value)
{
    auto clamp = [min_value, max_value](double x) {
        return std::min(std::max(x, min_value), max_value);
    };

    std::transform(input_image.begin(), input_image.end(),
                   input_image.begin(), clamp);
}
```

testing this on godbolt, gcc vectorised it and completely eliminated the redundant copy of `clamp`.

Answer (score 1):

There you go. I made two transforms just to give the compiler a better chance for optimizations and vectorization. You can join them if you wish in 1 lambda if you disagree.

```
std::transform(input_image.begin(), input_image.end(), input_image.begin(), [lo](double v) {return (v < lo ? lo : v);});
std::transform(input_image.begin(), input_image.end(), input_image.begin(), [hi](double v) {return (v > hi ? hi : v);});
```

Always keep in mind that looping over consecutive memory elements is much faster. Refer to [`std::transform` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to understand how it works.